# Java - Why am I getting an UnknownFormatConversionException?

Tags: java, exception, printf, double

Whenever I try to execute this line:

```
System.out.printf("%14s %-*.2f\n", "Minimum Range:", minRange); // minRange is a double
```

I get this error:

> java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-'

I can't seem to find anything wrong with my statement.  Unless I'm mistaken, `%-*.2f` should work just fine.

***Why is this wrong?***

***How can I specify an unlimited field that allows two decimal places?***

Comment: What format are you expecting from `%-*.2f`? Why?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It should allow a number of unlimited length, and only allow two digits after the decimal point.

Comment: I think you just need to get rid of your left justify flag... It's not really doing anything here `System.out.printf("%s %.2f\n", "Minimum Range:", 2000000000000000000.00);` prints the same thing as what I think you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, you want to print a number of unlimited length, and only allow two digits after the decimal point.

To do this you don't need to use -*.

Your answer would be :

```
System.out.printf("%14s %.2f\n", "Minimum Range:", minRange);
```

Using **-** (minus) flag means that you want to left justify your value. When you use that flag you should specify the width of the block you want to justify your text in.
In your case, you are specifying a width of * which is not valid.

Comment: @CurticeGough By leaving it without the left-justification, your float will automatically take up unlimited space... You only need to specify that you want it to be less justified when you want it to be a limited length, like this: `System.out.printf("%s %-9.2f %s\n", "Minimum Range:", 200.00, "another string");`

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know the left justify flag wasn't needed when you had unlimited length.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why you think "-*" are valid flags, but the correct format syntax should be (note also the `%n` for the platform specific line feed):

```
System.out.printf("%14s %0.2f%n", "Minimum Range:", minRange); // minRange is a double
```

Which is equal to (because the string variable has exactly 14 characters):

```
System.out.printf("%s %0.2f%n", "Minimum Range:", minRange);
```

Which again is equal to (and much easier to read):

```
System.out.printf("Minimum Range: %.2f%n", minRange);
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: `-` is definitely a valid flag... he was trying to explicitly tell it to left-justify. And he was using the `*` as an attempt at a wildcard to say he wanted any length to be allowed

Comment: Yes, `-` is, but `*` isn't. No need to left-justify a value if you don't specify a minimum length to be filled up with placeholders.